# Android Studio can't see TextView ID

Tags: java, android, textview, main-activity

I have a textview, the xml file is

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="30sp"
        android:text="MyText"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22000003" />
```

There is no ID of this textview so I can't use it in MainActivity.java, I just started Android Studio(I worked with Python so far) what am I missing?

I have also a button and it has an **id**.

Comment: Do you need to define *id* to *Text View* ? Or you need to use it in *Activity*  ? *Elaborate* more.

Comment: This textview was the default one with "Hello World!" So I thought it must have an ID by default.

Comment: You need to define id manually as *android:id="@+id/tvTest"* for your *Text View*. *tvTest* is an identifier of your *Text View* which you will use in your *Activity* to bind some data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    ... (rest of lines)
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22000003" />
```

*myTextView* will be the identifier you choose

Comment: But why it doesn't have an id by default anyways?

Comment: In every item i ever added, I had to add the id field... 

Another option is to add it in the Design properties, which will add it to the xml.

Other than that there are many cases a ID is not needed, since you would not reference it from anywhere in the Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind this:

When creating an XML layout file you must specify the Activity name value for the
tools:context like below:

```
tools:context=".views.QuestionActivity"
```

This will allow you to retrieve all the ids from the XML layout file in the specified activity.

Also if you have checked that everything is correct but still can't get the ids just restart the IDE.

Make also sure that in your "AndroidManifest.xml" file you have created the activity and assigned the correct name.